# Passing JSON from Unity Application to Firebase function with onCall results as undefined

Tags: json, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

Hey why are Firebase Logs telling me that following data is undefined:

**In unity i have following class:**

```
public class Question
{
    private string question;
    private string answerA;
    private string answerB;
    private string answerC;
    private string answerD;
    private string rightAnswer;

    public Question(string question, string answerA, string answerB, string answerC, string answerD, string rightAnswer)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answerA = answerA;
        this.answerB = answerB;
        this.answerC = answerC;
        this.answerD = answerD;
        this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    }

}
```

When i click a button i create a object of Question and transform it into a JSON:

```
submitButton.onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            Question myQuestion = new Question(questionField.text, answerAField.text, 
              answerBField.text, answerCField.text, answerDField.text, rightAnswer.text);
            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(myQuestion);
            firebaseManager.createQuestion(json);
        });
```

finally i pass the JSON string to following function:

```
 public void createQuestion(string json)
    {
        var function = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance.GetHttpsCallable("createQuestion");
        function.CallAsync(json).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted)
                Debug.Log("done");
        });
    }
```

My firebase function is just printing some fields of the JSON but the problem is that my firebase function says that the data is undefined:

```
exports.createQuestion = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log(data.answerA);
    console.log(data.answerB);

    return 0;
});
```

When i use a Dictionary<string,object> instead of the JSON string then it is working but i wanna know why the JSON solution is not working?

**SOLUTION**

had to change the code on the server:

```
exports.createQuestion = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    var myObject = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(myObject.answerA);
    console.log(myObject.answerB);
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put this attribute on top of your data class
   [System.Serializable]
   Classes without that wont serialize.
2. Make the fields you want to serialize public, Private fields wont serialize.

   ```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Question
    {
        public string question;
        public string answerA;
        public string answerB;
        public string answerC;
        public string answerD;
        public string rightAnswer;

        public Question(string question, string answerA, string answerB, string answerC, string answerD, string rightAnswer)
        {
            this.question = question;
            this.answerA = answerA;
            this.answerB = answerB;
            this.answerC = answerC;
            this.answerD = answerD;
            this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: thanks for your answer; i already had my class Serializable, just forgot to add it  in my post . but i am gonna switch the fields to public now!

Comment: for some reason it still tells me that data is undefined

Comment: @Clyon97 you can at least test is serialization working in C#. Write a test, turn an example object into a string with jsonutility. Then tyrn that string back into class with jsonutility and debug the fields, also debug the json string and see if it looks ok.

Comment: @Clyon97 Also in firebase console.log(data); and see what that says. Im not familiar with firebase, is that javascript? maybe that string needs to be turned from a string into a json object in firebase

Comment: yes its JavaScript; just noticed that the problem is how i log the data: data.answerA is not the right way to extract the fields from the JSON

Comment: just had to change server code to: var myObject =            
    JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(myObject.answerA);
    console.log(myObject.answerB);                                                          thanks for helping